# Inconsistent behavior in a php code

Tags: php, codeigniter, function, asynchronous

I coded a function to help me handle transaction with files in *CodeIgniter*.
today I was trying this code:

```
function($db_trans_func, $context){
    if(is_callable($db_trans_func)){
        $context = $db_trans_func($context);
        FirePHP_::info_(time(), "After Db trans");
    }
}
```

that is just a snippet from my helper. But the problem is, when this code runs and in the case where the execution of the function `$db_trans_func` takes place it takes more time to run, php passes to next code `FirePHP_::info_($context, "From db transaction");` before the ending of the line before.

That is abnormal for me. because in the normal case the lines should run one after the other.

Can anyone help me solve this problem ? How can I tell php to not run

```
FirePHP_::info_(time(), "After Db trans");
```

after that:

```
$context = $db_trans_func($context);
```

finishes its execution?

Comment: The words in the title make no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear, but my assumption is:

- db_trans_func is running some function against the DB (such as setting a transaction begin)
- you are comparing the php function FirePHP_::info_(time(), "After Db trans"); against the time recorded in the db, or similar

In other words, you have a function that DOES fire first in php, then a second one. They ARE running consecutively; BUT, the DB result takes longer, of course, and so the db effect is seen afterwards. In other words, these are different threads running asynchronously

Does that make sense to you, and is it possible?

Comment: The situation is like that :
    `function f1(Callable $f){
       $f();
       //Other code ...
    }`
My question is : Why the "other code" runs before the termination of the execution of `$f();` ? Is because that $f(); runs in its one thread or what's the reason ?

But, if i take the body of the function `$f()` and put it in the place of `$f()`, **it runs good**.

But my aim is to reuse the function `f1` like the design pattern _method factory_

Comment: how do you know when $f() has terminated? what is the measurement you are using?

Comment: Firstable i saw that in the user interface. After that i put a `time()`like that :
`$func = function(){ sleep(10); echo "End func : ". time();}  
function f1(Callable $f){ $f(); echo "End f1 : " . time();}  
//Whene i run this :  
$f1($func);  
//The output is :  
- End f1  
- End func`